# How to find values that don't exist in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a stock keeping table for perishables with up to 100 rows (hard limit, bad i know, but it is how it is for now).  The idea is that other processes run and deposit information into this table.  When a product is out of date, its row gets deleted from the table by an automated procedure, and it can then used for a new product.  The table essentially has the columns Product, ProductID (the 0-99 field), PurchaseDate and ExpiryDate.

To help with troubleshooting, I would like to write a query that shows any unused product IDs, but I can't figure out how to return only unused rows.  Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,
Brett

Comment: What scenario makes product unused? Is the date? Seems expirydate must be using to determine unused product?

Comment: select * from yourtable where expirydate < todaydate

Comment: Hi there, yes, it is expirydate.  A procedure runs periodically to delete any row where the product has expired. So say rows 0-95 are full, then product 45 expires, row 45 is deleted and the next product added will fill that slot.

Comment: After product 45 expires, I would like a query that returns me the empty rows, i.e. 45, 96, 97, 98, 99

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45252378/getting-first-10-unused-manual-sequence-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Get 99 minus used IDs:

```
SELECT  LEVEL 
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 99


minus 

select ProductID  from productleases where expirydate > sysdate
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried this but getting error that table doesn't exist.  My table is called productleases and i substituted it for DUAL in your example above, but no luck.

Comment: It seems likely that records in use will have `expirydate > sysdate`. Your query will return those IDs, which is the exact opposite of the OP's requirement.

Comment: Updated. Took it as is from user comments

Comment: Is there any way to add a second column to the output here.  If my produce is sorted into categories, so there are 100 leases available for meat, 100 for vegetables, can I return e.g.:
meat 76
meat 95
veg 22
veg 36
sweet 45

The column is called producttype.  Thanks.